# Jquery popup overlay - submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, overlay

I am using this jquery plugin ([Jquery Popup Overlay](https://github.com/vast-engineering/jquery-popup-overlay))

I have finally managed to have it working as expected, apart from the last step.

Once the pop up opens, there are 2 buttons. One is to close the window and one to progress with selected action(delete something in DB in this case).

I have this link to activate the window:

```
<a class="initialism basic_open btn btn-xs btn-danger" href="?page=suite-admin&action=delete-suite&id=5&site_id=1">delete suite</a></td>
```

This is the script to show the window:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  $('#basic').popup({
escape: false,
blur: false,  });});
```

What I need is , when pop up opens and i click on delete button this will progress with whatever is in .

I do not know much about Java, but i do really like this feature on my project.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Edit:

Forgot the actual pop up:

```
<div id="basic" class="well" style="display: none;">
<h4>Basic</h4>
<p>The dialog can be closed by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or by clicking on the background
<br> outside the content area, or by clicking on the Close button.</p>
<button class="basic_close btn btn-default">Close</button>
<button class="basic_close btn btn-danger">Delete Suite</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two possible answers (there are certainly more) to your problem can be found in this stackoverflow question: [[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link][1])

To sum it up: One way would be to just use an `<a>` tag instead of `<button>`. That means you write:

```
<a class="basic_close btn btn-danger" href="?page=suite-admin&action=delete-suite&id=5&site_id=1">Delete Suite</a>
```